# Hide / Show custom action in ribbon conditionally

Tags: 2010, development, custom-actions

I have a question regarding Custom actions:

Basically what I would like to have is a custom action to shown only when the `list.RootFolder.Properties.ContainsKey()`.

This action is located in the ribbon.

Any idea on how I can do that?

Comment: http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2011/07/24/hiding-ecb-custom-actions-based-on-specific-list-properties-using-the-client-object-model/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, I found a solution by creating custom action automatically when my feature by anyway is activated.

I used SPUserCustomAction, here is a piece of code for someone who will be interested, the code is shortned, but you will see the idea:

```
 SPUserCustomAction action = list.UserCustomActions.Add();
                action.Title = "";
                action.Description = "";
                action.Location = "CommandUI.Ribbon";
                action.Sequence = 10000;

                action.CommandUIExtension = @"<CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="">
          <Button />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler />
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>";
                action.Update();
```